# PreprocessQuery event in LightSwitch fails

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

In LightSwitch I have a PreprocessQuery event as follows:

```
partial void ValidOrders_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Order> query)
{
    query = query.Where(order => OrderIsValid(order));
}

public bool OrderIsValid(Order order)
{
    return true;
}
```

This fails with a message (on the HTMLClient side !) "method cannot be null".

But this works fine:

```
partial void ValidOrders_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Order> query)
{
    query = query.Where(order => true);
}
```

Can someone see why?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query provider is only shown the method `OrderIsValid`, and as that method has already been compiled down to IL it can no longer "look into it" to see it's implementation, as it would need to to create `Expression` objects to represent it.

There are a number of options that you have, ranging from inlining the method as you did yourself, or having the method itself return an expression, rather than doing the work:

```
public Expression<Func<Order, bool>> OrderIsValid()
{
    return order => true;
}
```

This would let you write:

```
partial IQueryable<Order> ValidOrders_PreprocessQuery(IQueryable<Order> query)
{
    return query.Where(OrderIsValid());
}
```

As a side note, I would strongly advise you to not pass the query by reference, but rather return a new query instead; that would be the more idiomatic approach.

Comment: Thank you, Servy, this helps.

By the way: I agree on your remark about passing the query by reference, but LightSwitch not me defines the prototype of the method.

Comment: @Servy - you can't change the query's parameters in any way, nor can you return a "new query" as you suggest. The only mechanism that LightSwitch provides is a "query parameter" that is passed by reference. So to return a filtered set of entities, you have to return the results via the provided query parameter. While doing it the way you describe might well be the more "idiomatic" approach, it's not the way LightSwitch does things.

Comment: @YannDuran If that's the only option, then so be it; it doesn't really change the important parts of the answer, and it's useful for other readers that don't have such a constraint.

Comment: @Servy - I was just letting you know, but this question is actually about LightSwitch, so while what you described can be done elsewhere, it's actually not applicable to any LightSwitch application (which will *always* have that constraint), so it's important that anyone reading this thread be aware of that